# Порядок инициализации в конструкторе наследуемого класса

Tags: c++, наследование

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    X(int x) : x{x} {};

    int x = 0;
};

struct Y : X {
    Y(int x, int y) : y{y + this->x}, X{x} {}

    int y;
};

int main() {
    Y y{1, 2};

    std::cout << y.x << ' ' << y.y << '\n';
}
```

Почему выводит `1 3`? Другими словами, что инициализируется первым: `Y::x` или `Y::y` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок вызова конструкторов в списке инициализации, как ни странно, роли не играет. Сначала инициализируются все базовые классы, в том порядке, в котором они наследуются (за исключением виртуального наследования), затем поля данного класса, в том порядке, в котором они объявлены. Так что сначала инициализируется `X::x` а потом `Y::y`

Comment: В примере конструктор для `X` будет вызван 1 раз или 2?

Comment: @brut Только 1.

Comment: То есть компилятор как бы сортирует список инициализиции, чтобы он соответствовал порядку объявления?

Comment: @brut Ну да....